# Why would some high profile blog not allow commenting?

Tags: user-behavior, psychology, comments, blog, cognition

Comments have been an important part from the evolution of blog. But I can see some blogs like http://www.lukew.com not allowing comments at all.

It surely hurts the user experience for genuine commenters. I would like to know the psychology/science behind this.

Comment: Spamers, low quality comments, Black SEO URL. Also somebody need moderate it, so better enable comments when you really need . If you had High quality content comments can only make i less valuable

Comment: Instead of asking us to just guess (which is likely all we can do) why not just tweet the blog owners themselves and ask them? https://twitter.com/lukew

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this can have a couple of different reasons – here's just some thoughts:

- Moderation of comments can be a lot of work – especially if you have a popular blog and you're writing all by yourself. For a high quality, high traffic blog I would estimate that moderating incoming comments may take as much time as writing the actual articles.
- If the nature of the blog is rather '*broadcasting*' than '*discussing*' comments may not make sence. If you want to push the nature of your blog towards '*broadcasting*' you may want to avoid comments from the very beginning. (The author of the blog you mentioned also writes books (wrote a book) and a.f.a.i.k. also gives talks at conferences and the like – I would consider both more on the '*broadcasting*' side.)

The increase of *somment spam* (be it for seo-reasons or whatever reasons) makes things even worse:

- Popular blogs are popular targets because they have the potential to drive a lot of traffic to third party sites – and (if e.g. "nofollow" is not on) even improve the ranking of linked pages.
- Popular blogs are easy to find for potential spammers – which makes the above even worse. As a result of both you have more spammers than a 'regular' blog **and** they more motivated to actually place their content in the comments.

and last but not least:

- The popularity of so called *social media platforms* makes it easy to allow a certain amount of comments / certain type of discussion while moderation efforts can be kept at a minimum. While the blog you mentioned only provides a link to twitter and a RSS-Feed I suppose many other popular blogs have pages on google+ and facebook where people may leave comments related to blog posts. Discussion on social media *can* drive additional traffic to the blog while discussion on-site *cen* generate additional work.
- IMHO you are of course always welcome to comment on whatever blog post you want to comment on – just not always on the blog's server. So if you rund your own blog, you may want to comment in your own blog post about an article you read. Chances are that you'll link back to the blog post you're commenting on. And that can be actually way more valuable to the other blog than maintaining an on-site list of comments.

ps: in my opinion the second reason regarding the 'nature' of the blog is the most important. So if you **want** to allow comments, then there will be a way – no matter how much time you'll spend on moderating, installing anti-spam plug-ins and the like. But if you simply don't, then you simply don't.

Comment: Good points, although I din't get the last one (the one starting with IMHO), specially the part of being more valuable, which situation is more valuable than what other?

Comment: I was refering to blogs commenting on blogs –– or actually people writing blog posts (on their own blogs) about other people's blog posts. Lot's of people have their own blog and instead of writhing a comment **on the very article page**, everybody is free to write a comment **on whatever platform** one prefers. And those backlinks that *may* be found on such 'refering' / 'commenting' blog posts ***can*** be more valuable concerning seo than on-site comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one reason might be trolling, which has become a serious problem these days. Even come to the extent that groups of people like students are paid to troll. Comment threads are good as long as discussions are productive. but with trolling and hate speech these days, comment threads easily go off topic and turn sour and make even the blog look bad